# Printing an ansible task elapsed time into a log file

Tags: performance, automation, callback, ansible, analytics

I have a playbook that I have developed and I want to log the elapsed time of each execution of that playbook to log file. I have already enabled callback_plugins, but I do not know how to print them to a log file. Is there a way to register the elapsed time into a variable or is there a mechanism that I have missed to do this task

Answer (score 1):

For ansible > 2.0, the plugin named callback comes as built-in. To enable add the shown directive to ansible.cfg. I have used and it is working as expected.

```
#/etc/ansible/ansible.cg

callback_whitelist = profile_tasks
```

Also, login is off by default so provide a log path. For example -

```
# Logging is off by default unless this path is defined.
#log_path = /var/log/ansible.log
```